# Add itemprop attribute to img tag created by amp-img

Tags: amp-html, microdata, amp-img

I am currently working on creating an e-commerce product detail page using AMP. As part of the work, I want to be able to provide valid [structured data for each product](https://schema.org/Product) to assist with SEO.

I'm running into an issue trying to add the structured data attribute of `itemprop="image"` to the product's hero image that is being rendered by using `amp-img`. From what I can tell, there is no way to apply custom attributes to the `img` tag that `amp-img` will ultimately render.

My existing markup:

```html
<amp-img on="tap:hero-zoom-lightbox" src="--REDACTED--" [src]="productState.currentHeroImg" width="260" height="260" layout="responsive"
class="hero-carousel-image" role="button" tabindex="0" itemprop="image"></amp-img>
```

What gets rendered:

```html
<amp-img itemprop="image" tabindex="0" role="button" class="hero-carousel-image amp-carousel-slide i-amphtml-element i-amphtml-layout-responsive i-amphtml-layout-size-defined i-amphtml-layout" layout="responsive" height="260" width="260" data-amp-bind-src="productState.currentHeroImg" i-amphtml-binding="" src="--REDACTED--" on="tap:hero-zoom-lightbox" i-amphtml-layout="responsive" aria-hidden="false">
    <i-amphtml-sizer style="padding-top: 100%;"></i-amphtml-sizer>
    <img decoding="async" src="--REDACTED--" class="i-amphtml-fill-content i-amphtml-replaced-content">
</amp-img>
```

What I'm looking for (`itemprop="image"` attribute is on the `img` tag itself):

```html
<amp-img tabindex="0" role="button" class="hero-carousel-image amp-carousel-slide i-amphtml-element i-amphtml-layout-responsive i-amphtml-layout-size-defined i-amphtml-layout" layout="responsive" height="260" width="260" data-amp-bind-src="productState.currentHeroImg" i-amphtml-binding="" src="--REDACTED--" on="tap:hero-zoom-lightbox" i-amphtml-layout="responsive" aria-hidden="false">
    <i-amphtml-sizer style="padding-top: 100%;"></i-amphtml-sizer>
    <img itemprop="image" decoding="async" src="--REDACTED--" class="i-amphtml-fill-content i-amphtml-replaced-content">
</amp-img>
```

Does anyone have any insight into whether or not this is possible? If not, any reason why implementing such behavior would break AMP paradigms?

Comment: In case there is no solution: a workaround is to add a `link` element, and specify the `itemprop` on the link instead of the (`amp-`)`img`.

Comment: @unor Very helpful suggestion, thank you!

Comment: @pstricker Why would you need it on the `img` tag over the `amp-img` tag? Wouldn't having the `itemprop="image"` on a link be the same as having it on the `amp-img`? They are both containers holding the `img` tag.

Comment: @TrevorGeene That's an excellent question that I don't have a good answer to. Running the markup with `itemprop="image"` attribute on the `amp-img` element through Google's structured data testing tool, the image property is not recognized. Conversely, using `itemprop="image"` on a `link` element is recognized. I haven't found any explicit documentation as to why `link` works opposed to any other arbitrary element, but am still researching.

Comment: @pstricker While I have used Google's testing tool I guess I overlooked the fact that the `itemprop="image"` as missing (I even just confirmed it).

Answer (score 0):

I resolved this issue by using adding `itemprop="image"` in the surrounding `anchor tag`

This way it'll resolve the SEO error and would validate on AMP validator as well.

I previously tried using a hidden image element which solved the SEO issue but resulted in AMP validation error `<img src="/imgUrl" alt="/altUrl" itemprop="image" class="hidden" />`